# VS Code Omnisharp throws error on restart attempt

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

So it all started with me reinstalling Windows 11. I installed Unity and VS Code as usual, I installed my preferred extensions to VS Code, I opened up a script and noticed something strange - CodeLens doesn't work at all (it was working prior to OS reinstallation, and there were no problems at all - I got all the references above fields and methods, I got the "Go to definition" action in context menu).

- I tried disabling all of the extensions, except official MS's C# extension
- I tried completely reinstalling VS Code
- I tried with .cs files completely unrelated to Unity
- I tried new project in Unity
- I tried different versions of VS Code, including 1.73, 1.74, 1.75 and VS Code Insiders (1.76). (Prior to reinstall I had 1.74 and it worked)
- I tried deleting all the user preferences in `users/username/.vscode` and `appdata/roaming/code` folders.
- I tried installing all the .NET packages I am aware of.

None of it helped.

After a decent amount of time and frustration, on google I found that after some update (apparently in March-May of 2022, which is completely unrelated because I used more recent version and it worked, but I still tried this fix, because it's the only one I found) MS has set in settings "Omnisharp: Use Modern Net" to true by default. And some people suggested to disable it and to reload Omnisharp. So I did. After unchecking the setting, VS Code automatically suggests to restart Omnisharp, and when I hit restart, I get such an output:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 2/20/2023, 3:13:09 PM
    Target: c:\gamedev\unity-projects\CubeWorld\CubeWorld.sln

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: c:\Users\vasya\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.4-win32-x64\.omnisharp\1.39.4\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 14996

[STDERR] Could not locate MSBuild instance to register with OmniSharp.

[ERROR] Error: OmniSharp server load timed out. Use the 'omnisharp.projectLoadTimeout' setting to override the default delay (one minute).
```

I've no idea what is MSBuild and what is its instance and how can I provide Omnisharp with it. Some people suggest to install some version of .NET (which I already did, but I'm never sure I installed the right version, cause there's no clarification anywhere which version it needs, and if it needs .NET at all or it's an error about something else).

Also, on VS Code startup, I get this error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjuMk.png)

I don't think it's related to the aforementioned problem, because, again, prior to OS reinstall, I had it and successfully ignored it, and CodeLens worked. But I think I must mention it still.

As for it - none of the suggestions from the internet help. They include:

1. Install x86 version of .NET
2. Close VS Code and reinstall .NET SDK

Comment: Have you installed .NET Developers Tools?

Comment: @Obscure021 Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022 from the following link:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2022

---

### Reference:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity#_install-build-tools-for-visual-studio-windows-only